# Directing %PSOURCE into output cell for iPython

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Running "%PSOURCE func" opens up a pane below that displays the source. Is there a way to change the behavior so that the source is directed to the corresponding output cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665118/how-to-show-source-code-of-a-package-function-in-ipython-notebook) (after yours - I should have checked in more detail). There is a quick hack there that works but should probably be improved, and a useful answer on its limitations.

Note that the point of my question was about displaying a single function from a file, appropriately highlighted: if you actually want to run it (as eg the *%load* magic would give you for the full file), you'll probably want to just use the inpect.getmembers functionality.